# If I have a file containing a virus, and I open the file programatically in a Java program, will the virus activate?

Tags: java, virus

A file contains a virus, this virus will not be activated unless the file is executed.

Does opening the file in java cause it to be executed, and thus the virus activated, e.g. using

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

Comment: Reading a file is not executing its code so you are safe :)

Comment: Step 1: Create a simple .exe that performs any kind of action. Step 2: Open it using your method. Step 3: check if it performed the action. Step 4: Profit!

Comment: The question seems better fit for [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ŁukaszKapica, famous last words. What if the file that's being read has been carefully crafted to exploit a zero-day vulnerability in the JVM's stream handling code?

Comment: @MickMnemonic, sure you're right but question was a little bit different, it was: "Does opening the file in java cause it to be executed" and in theory the answer is no, it shouldn't - according to documentation and that's all. It's up to us if we trust Java and JVM.

Comment: Thankyou all for your comments and answering so quickly, I have accepted the answer that reading a file in Java which contains a virus will not activate the virus, because the file was not designed to be opened in Java so is unlikely to contain a JVM-related exploit, I perhaps should have stated this in my question. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using `FileReader`, or any other method of reading the file in Java, will not activate the virus.

Comment: Are you _sure_ and if so, _how_?

Comment: In theory, there could be a flaw in the Java VM where it would start executing byte codes out of data read in.  And in theory, somebody could create a data file to exploit that.  **Extremely unlikely**.  Reading some other virus, like "ILOVEYOU" or whatever, is even less likely to be a problem.

Comment: It's not that far-fetched; there was a [recent exploit](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/11/commons-exploit) that targeted object deserialization, which is basically "reading from a file" (albeit binary).

Comment: Thankyou for replying so quickly, I will accept this answer thankyou John because the file in question was not designed to be opened in Java  so unlikely to contain a JVM-related exploit, and also thankyou Mick for your discussion, the link to the deserialization exploit was an interesting and scary read

Comment: In some sense the deserialization "exploit" is "working as designed" -- you have a method for transmitting an object from one program to another -- if you accept an object from an untrustworthy source, you pretty much get what you deserve.  But it's really not a Java flaw any more than a bad web page that lets you do an injection attack is a flaw in SQL.